# Massive wait time in my java application

Tags: java, sleep, profile

I am working on an application that consists of 3 JVM's, which each communicate through IBM JMS messaging. In a production environment I am observing below par performance, so of course fired up VisualVM and started profiling. Under my "Sampler" view, I can see one of my JVM's has a huge amount of wait time, as can be seen in the below screenshot. I've read conflicting reports all over the place, would this actually be impacting my performance or is the profiler simply saying there's something just sitting around?

[image]

Comment: Did you measure a performance problem? Then you have one, an should post some code that exhibits the problem. If you did not measure or observe a performance problem, you are doing premature optimization.

Comment: Think logically: if you observe subdue performance in one environment and not in the other, the problem is likely to be with the environment. How you application interacts with that environment? Via IO. What do you see in the above screenshot? socketRead and socketAccept. I suspect you problem in prod is not with objects waiting (this seems to be an ugly feature of your application), but with network or disk IO.